# add location search to openlayers map

Tags: openlayers-2, geocoding

I am trying to figure out how to add a search functionality to my openlayers map. I want the user to type in an address and the map to zoom into the location. I am looking at different geocoders and can't figure out a simple solution to this. Nominatim seems liek a possible solution. But I am trying to find something that I can develop on the front end. I have OSM data for my background and would prefer to use this. Any tip or ideas to point me in the right direction would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[Here's an example using google.](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/topp/almanac/examples/geocoder.html)

Just supply your own google key for your environment to test.

Comment: can't we do this with out google support?

Comment: @RameshK : yes we can! :)

Comment: This might be better as its own question, but I want to use a customized Google address search that I already developed and with an openlayers map. @CaptDragon I took your example using Google and added the latest openlayers js `<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/2.11/OpenLayers.js"></script>` but I'm getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: OpenLayers.Control.Geocoder is not a constructor. Do you know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To attach such a functionality, you can use [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim).