# Add a custom search to an OpenLayers map

Tags: openlayers-2, reverse-geocoding

I have looked at this thread: [add location search to openlayers map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23635/add-location-search-to-openlayers-map)
but it is not the result that I am trying to achieve.

Probably best if iI show you: http://www.potholestudios.com/Content/pid=46.html

I have made this Interactive Game Map using OpenLayers. What I would like to do is add a search box, so when say someone types into a search box "Deep Space 9" the map would fly to coordinates (-33.87, -8.58) Deep Space 9 in the Beta Ursae sector block.

Now, I'm guessing I'd have to list the X,Y coordinates of every system in a list with names. So that when a name is entered in a search box it moves the map to the listed coordinates.

But I have no idea even where to start with this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm guessing I'd have to list the X,Y coordinates of every system in a
>   list with Names. So that when a Name is Entered in a Search Box it
>   moves the map to the listed coordinates.

Your idea is correct, you need to take a look this: [Search functionality in Openlayers/Geoserver](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11167/search-functionality-in-openlayers-geoserver)

Basically, the demo that would work for you is this (you need to refresh a couple of times to get it working):

```
http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver/www/search/gazetteer.html
```

and its instructions:

```
http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/apps/gaz/index.html
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I will take a look at the links soon.